# SWIG python module creation issue

Tags: c++, python, windows, swig

I have c++ classes that are needed to import in python.
For that I am using SWIG. Below is the swig interface

example.i

```
/* File: example.i */
%module example

%{
#include "Item.h"
#include "GradedDouble.h"
#include "GradedComplex.h"
%}

%include <std_string.i>
%include <std_complex.i>
%include "Item.h"
%include "GradedDouble.h"
%include "GradedComplex.h"  

%template(Int) Item<int>;
%template(Complex) Item<std::complex<double> >;
```

And for creating wrapper class and python module I am executing following command in windows XP environment

```
c:\>swig -c++ -python -nodefaultctor example.i 
c:\>python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

After executing second command I am getting the following error :

```
*C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\link.exe /DLL /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Python26\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Python26\PCbuild /EXPORT:init_example build\temp.win32-2.6\Release\example_wrap.obj "/OUT:C:\Documents and Settings\swig_example.pyd" /IMPLIB:build\temp.win32-2.6\Release\_example.lib /MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win32-2.6\Release\_example.pyd.manifest
   Creating library build\temp.win32-2.6\Release\_example.lib and object build\temp.win32-2.6\Release\_example.exp
example_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall GradedDouble::~GradedDouble(void)" (??1GradedDouble@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function __wrap_delete_GradedDouble
example_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall GradedComplex::~GradedComplex(void)" (??1GradedComplex@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function __wrap_delete_GradedComplex
example_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall GradedDouble::GradedDouble(int,double *)" (??0GradedDouble@@QAE@HPAN@Z) referenced in function __wrap_new_GradedDouble
example_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall GradedDouble::avg(double *)" (?avg@GradedDouble@@QAEXPAN@Z) referenced in function __wrap_GradedDouble_avg
example_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall GradedComplex::GradedComplex(int,double *)" (??0GradedComplex@@QAE@HPAN@Z) referenced in function __wrap_new_GradedComplex
example_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall GradedComplex::avg(double *)" (?avg@GradedComplex@@QAEXPAN@Z) referenced in function __wrap_GradedComplex_avg
example_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall GradedComplex::push(class Item<class std::complex<double> >)" (?push@GradedComplex@@QAEXV?$Item@V?$complex@N@std@@@@@Z) referenced in function __wrap_GradedComplex_push
example_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall GradedDouble::push(class Item<double>)" (?push@GradedDouble@@QAEXV?$Item@N@@@Z) referenced in function __wrap_GradedDouble_push
C:\Documents and Settings\swig_example.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 8 unresolved externals
error: command '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\link.exe"'failed with exit status 1120*
```

It seems there are issue in creating interface file of swig (example.i)
I need help for creating interface file. Following are the header files

**GradedComplex.h**

```
#ifndef __GRADEDCOMPLEX_H__
#define __GRADEDCOMPLEX_H__
#include <complex>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include "Item.h"
class GradedComplex
{
public:
  typedef std::complex<double> dcomplex;
  typedef Item<dcomplex> item_type;
  typedef ItemComparator<dcomplex> comparator;
  typedef std::set<item_type, comparator> grade_type;
private:
  int n_;
  std::vector<grade_type *> grade_;
  std::vector<double> thre_;
public:
  GradedComplex(int n, double *thre);
  ~GradedComplex();
  void push(item_type item);
  void avg(double *buf);
};
#endif
```

**Graded Double.h**

```
#ifndef __GRADEDDOUBLE_H__
#define __GRADEDDOUBLE_H__
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include "Item.h"
class GradedDouble
{
public:
  typedef Item<double> item_type;
  typedef ItemComparator<double> comparator;
  typedef std::set<item_type, comparator> grade_type;
private:
  int n_;
  std::vector<grade_type *> grade_;
  std::vector<double> thre_;
public:
  GradedDouble(int n, double *thre);
  ~GradedDouble();
  void push(item_type item);
  void avg(double *buf);
};
#endif
```

Please help me for creating correct SWIG interface file.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the link operation is missing the definitions for your `GradedDouble` and `GradedComplex` classes.

You have to provide these definitions to the linker, either in the form of object files, or in the form of a library.

I don't know enough about SWIG on Windows (only use it on Linux) to be able to help further on how to solve this.